# Way to fix Visual Studio 2008 Redraw Problem?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Sometimes when working with Visual Studio 2008, the main editor window will just start failing to draw beyond a certain width. In this case it appears to only re-draw about 80% of the editor width, then it starts showing grey/incomplete rendering. See this screenshot:

[image]

I have no idea what's going on here; anyone else experience this issue? If I restart Visual Studio it seems fine again for a while. I've got the latest videocard drivers on my computer, and it has happened on different computers of mine. Has even happened on a "stock" install of VS2008.

I'm in Windows 7 Ultimate, 64-bit if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

It happens to me also but in Windows XP, It appears is a video card problem, what I had to do is turn of hardware acceleration, not a perfect solution.